# How to prevent Phusion Passenger from overwriting Rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, logging, passenger

I'm testing Passenger with nginx and in my log/development.log file, it looks like every SQL requests are triggered by Passenger:

```
Decidim::Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "decidim_organizations".* FROM "decidim_organizations" WHERE "decidim_organizations"."host" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["host", "decidim.domain.tld"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:107
```

Although it looks like the expected behavior, is there any way to add to the stack trace the file:line from the application ?

I'd like to have something like:

```
Decidim::Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "decidim_organizations".* FROM "decidim_organizations" WHERE "decidim_organizations"."host" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["host", "decidim.domain.tld"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /home/user/ror_app/app/models/something.rb:42
```

Adding `config.log_level = :debug` & restarting the server did not helped.

Answer (score 1):

you could `add_silencer` (ignoring) those lines which contains 'phusion_passenger' (or better: 'passenger') to [BacktraceCleaner](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html)

```rb
# config/initializers/backtrace_silencer.rb
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| /phusion_passenger/.match?(line) }
```

**update**

basically when you silence those `passenger` lines, then it should show your application log, for example, i assume log lines as below

```rb
Decidim::Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT ...
↳ /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:107
↳ another phusion_passenger
↳ /home/user/ror_app/app/models/something.rb:42
...
```

if you silence `phusion_passenger` lines then the log should show `/home/user/ror_app/app/models/something`

take a look at [the log_subscriber code on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L127-L137)

in case of there are still many other lines in between, to make sure that the log will show the first line of code of your app, you could override the log_subscriber code above to ignore lines until reach the code line in your app.

```rb
# your_app/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb 
module ActiveRecord
  class LogSubscriber
    def extract_query_source_location(locations)
      # old code
      # backtrace_cleaner.clean(caller.lazy).first
   
      # new code: to make sure that you log the line of code in your app, 
      # you could replace the regex `/app/` by `/app\/model.../` or
      # whatever you want to reach the code you want to show in logs
      locations.lazy.filter { |line| /app/.match?(line) }.first # first(3)
    end
  end
end 

# config/initializers/ext_core.rb
require File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "active_record", "log_subcriber.rb")
```

**update**

i think [active-record-query-trace](https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace) could help you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't really want to silence these lines, but rather see from which file and line from the application it comes from. The only way I've found is running the server locally, though I'm wondering if it's possible when the stack includes an external web server (here Passenger & nginx)

Comment: @Sumak basically when you silence those passenger lines, then it should show your application log. You also could force to show the first line of code of your app, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Sumak i found a gem i think it'll support your case: https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Will give it a try when I've free time (issue is on a side-project).